# Test fails. Throwing exceptions, Injection of autowired dependencies failed. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit4

My test methods throwing exceptions.

This is my beans.xml file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql:inf5750" />
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="user" value="dhis" />
    <property name="password" value="dhis" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="DataSource" ref="DataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate\Course.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate\Degree.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate\Student.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="course"  class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao" />
<bean id="degree"  class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateDegreeDao" />
<bean id="student" class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateStudentDao" />
<bean id="studentsystem" class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem">
    <property name="courseDao" ref="course"/>
    <property name="degreeDao" ref="degree"/>
    <property name="studentDao" ref="student"/>
</bean>
```

This is my TestClass:

```
package no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao;
import no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.model.Course;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class CourseDAOTest {

@Autowired
private HibernateCourseDao courseDao;

public HibernateCourseDao getCourseDao() {
    return courseDao;
}

public void setCourseDao(HibernateCourseDao courseDao) {
    this.courseDao = courseDao;
}

@Test
public void testSaveCourse() {
    Course sampleCourse = new Course( "INF5750", "Open Source Software Development" );
    int courseId = getCourseDao().saveCourse(sampleCourse);
    Course testCourse = getCourseDao().getCourse(courseId);

    assertEquals(courseId, testCourse.getId());     
}

}
```

Note: My test classes ran initially. But after I put @Transactional annotation in my DAO class it starts throwing exceptions.

Here is my full stacktrace:

```
* ERROR 14:43:16,206 Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a03e5af] to prepare test instance [no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAOTest@75dc5180] (TestContextManager.java [main])
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAOTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAOTest.courseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAOTest.courseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 28 more
```

Comment: You should post your full stacktrace

Comment: Try to use for autowired interface instead class. Maybe useful for you will be this link too: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/80224-issue-injecting-transactional-dao-object-into-unit-test